# Same texture being put on each image - JOGL

Tags: java, jogl

I am using JOGL to create a 2D game. In my game it has square blocks that each have a different type e.g water, grass, etc.
I have an ArrayList of the class Block. Each block instance has the type of block it is and coordinates. 
My problem is that when drawing the blocks they each have the same texture instead of the type they are. I think it may be because I need to disable the texture after using it but that seems to remove the texture off of everything.

GLCanvas Class

```
float[] lightPos = new float[4];


private void doLighting( GL2 gl )
{
   lightPos[0] =0.5f;
   lightPos[1] = 0;
    lightPos[2] = 1f;
  lightPos[3] = 0.0001f;
    gl.glEnable(GLLightingFunc.GL_LIGHTING);
    gl.glEnable(GLLightingFunc.GL_LIGHT0);
    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    float[] noAmbient ={ 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1f }; // low ambient light
    float[] spec =    { 1f, 1f, 1f,1f }; // low ambient light
    float[] diffuse ={ 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f };
    // properties of the light
    gl.glLightfv(GLLightingFunc.GL_LIGHT0, GLLightingFunc.GL_AMBIENT, noAmbient, 0);
    gl.glLightfv(GLLightingFunc.GL_LIGHT0, GLLightingFunc.GL_SPECULAR, spec, 0);
    gl.glLightfv(GLLightingFunc.GL_LIGHT0, GLLightingFunc.GL_DIFFUSE, diffuse, 0);
    gl.glLightfv(GLLightingFunc.GL_LIGHT0, GLLightingFunc.GL_POSITION, lightPos, 0);
  gl.glLightf(GL2.GL_LIGHT0, GL2.GL_SPOT_CUTOFF, 45.0f);
}

private void render(GL2 gl) {
    gl.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);          // Clear The Screen And The Depth Buffer
    gl.glLoadIdentity();                          // Reset The Current Modelview Matrix
    //Draw the blocks from the Block Array List
    for(int i = 0; i < block.size(); i ++){
        block.get(i).draw(gl, moveX, moveY);
    }
    //Draw player
    gl.glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
    gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_QUADS);
    gl.glVertex2f(player.x,player.y);
    gl.glVertex2f(player.x + player.width,player.y);
    gl.glVertex2f(player.x + player.width,player.y + player.width);
    gl.glVertex2f(player.x,player.y + player.width);
    gl.glEnd();
}

@Override
public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
     GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
     gl.glClear(GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_BLEND);
        gl.glBlendFunc(GL2.GL_ONE, GL2.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL2.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL2.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        gl.glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        doLighting(gl);
        setCamera(gl,120);
        render(gl);
}

@Override
public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable arg0) {
}

@Override
public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
     GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
     gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
 private void setCamera(GL2 gl,float distance) {
        // Change to projection matrix.
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();

        // Perspective.
        gl.glOrtho(0, Frame.WIDTH, Frame.HEIGHT, 0, 0, 1);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);

        //Disable z axis
        gl.glDisable(GL2.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    }

@Override
public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3,
        int arg4) {
}
```

Block class draw method

```
public void draw(GL2 gl, int moveX, int moveY) {

    if (texture == null) {

        try {
            texture = TextureIO.newTexture(new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader()
                    .getResource("com/world/images/" + type + ".png").getPath()), false);
               texture.enable(gl);
                texture.bind(gl);
                // Poor filtering. Needed !
                gl.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL2.GL_NEAREST);
                gl.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL2.GL_NEAREST);
        } catch (GLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_QUADS);
    gl.glVertex2f(x * width + moveX, y * width + moveY);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    gl.glVertex2f(x * width + width + moveX, y * width + moveY);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(1, 0);  
    gl.glVertex2f(x * width + width + moveX, y * width + width + moveY);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    gl.glVertex2f(x * width + moveX, y * width + width + moveY);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    gl.glEnd();
    gl.glFlush();
}
```

Thank you very much for any help. Ask if I have made anything unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

texture.enable() and texture.bind() had to be outside the if statement as they need to be called each time the textures are drawn.

```
public void draw(GL2 gl, int moveX, int moveY) {

    if (texture == null) {
        try {
            texture = TextureIO.newTexture(
                    new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("com/world/images/" + type + ".png").getPath()), false);
        } catch (GLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    texture.enable(gl);
    texture.bind(gl);
    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_QUADS);
    gl.glVertex2f(x * width + moveX, y * width + moveY);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    gl.glVertex2f(x * width + width + moveX, y * width + moveY);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    gl.glVertex2f(x * width + width + moveX, y * width + width + moveY);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    gl.glVertex2f(x * width + moveX, y * width + width + moveY);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    gl.glEnd();
    gl.glDisable(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D);


}
```

Comment: Your code works but it doesn't mean it's correct. As your texture uses the GL_TEXTURE_2D target, texture.enable(gl) has the same effect than gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D) but this texture target must be enabled before binding the texture. gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D) and gl.glDisable(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D) shouldn't be called each time you draw a single block/mesh but once per drawing session, for example in GLEventListener.display(GLAutoDrawable drawable).

Comment: If several instances of your Block class uses exactly the same image and if you store the texture into a (non static) field, your code will create several identical textures with the same image which is a huge waste of memory. You should rather create a single texture per image. If you use a single instance of block per block type (for example a single "water" Block instance to draw all blocks containing water), there is no such problem.

Comment: Okay that makes sense thank you. I have removed gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D) and gl.glDisable(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D) and as you said it works fine. Also I have now created a static field containing the each type of texture so that it doesn't load one image for each block instance. Thank you very much as this has all taught me quite a lot about openGl.

Comment: You're welcome. Please edit your code above so that I can upvote ;) Feel free to contact all JogAmp users and maintainers on IRC or on our official forum, we rarely come here.

Answer (score 0):

Move the calls of gl.glTexParameteri() into the init() method of your GLEventListener, it should be called only once, it affects the whole texture target, not only a single texture and I'm not sure you need to call bind before. Load each texture matching with a block type once elsewhere, call gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D) before drawing any textured mesh, call texture.bind(gl) (use the texture that matches with the block type) before calling glBegin() and call gl.glDisable(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D) after drawing the last textured mesh.

Comment: I believe I have made all the changes you have mentioned but no luck so far.Whatever block that is the last to  be drawn in the for loop is the type that each blocks texture is set to.

Comment: Are there any other possible causes? I've tried changing many things around but no luck.

Comment: Please post a sscce: http://www.sscce.org You should look at which texture you bind, the problem probably comes from that. Maybe you did another mistake, maybe you overwrite the textures of all types with the first or the last one.